# How to start a function only on a button click (JS)

Tags: javascript, function, button, dom-events

I am looking to have my grid style game start once I click the start button on my page.
Currently the game starts as soon as I click the grid, but I want this function to be invoked only when the you click the Start Button.

I already created my game Board. Which can be called using this function:
createBoard(). Styling for this board is full of my divs and working.
Here is part of my code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
  const startBtn = document.querySelector('.button-one')
  const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('.button-two')
  const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('.score')
  const countdown = document.querySelector('.countdown')
  let paused = true
  let score = 100
  const width = 8
  const squares = []
  let isGameOver = false
  let buzzyAmount = 12
  let result = 0

  const fiBuzz = [
    'url(images/purple-fizzy.png)',
    'url(images/buzzy-green.png)',
    'url(images/new-moo-buzzy.png)',
    'url(images/new-shiny-fizzy.png)'
  ]

  //shuffled Arrays

  function createBoard() {

    const buzzArray = Array(buzzyAmount).fill('buzzy')
    const emptyArray = Array(width * width - buzzyAmount).fill('valid')
    const gameArray = emptyArray.concat(buzzArray)
    const shuffledArray = gameArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)


    for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * fiBuzz.length)
      let square = document.createElement('div')
      square.setAttribute('id', i)
      square.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')
      square.classList.add(shuffledArray[i])
      grid.appendChild(square)
      squares.push(square)
      square.style.backgroundImage = fiBuzz[randomNumber]

      //normal click
      square.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        click(square)
      })
    }
  

  // game over

  function gameOver(square) {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + '<br>' + ' You Lose :('
    isGameOver = true
    clearInterval(timerId)

    // show ALL the badStars in gameOver 
    squares.forEach(square => {
      if (square.classList.contains('buzzy')) {
        square.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = 'images/fizz-buzz-mix.png'
        square.classList.remove('buzzy')
        square.classList.add('checked')
        clearInterval(timerId)
      }
    })
  }

  function checkForWin() {

    let matches = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      if (score >= 100) {
        scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + ': ' + ' You Win!'
      } else {
        scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + ': ' + ' You Lose!'
      }
      clearInterval(timerId)
    }
  }

  // TIMER LOGIC

  const startingMinutes = .25
  let time = startingMinutes * 60
  let timerId
  let square

  function countDown() {

    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    let seconds = time % 60
    time--
    console.log(minutes, 'minutes:', seconds, 'seconds')


    if (time <= 0) {
      checkForWin()
      gameOver()
    }

    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '
  }


  // START AND PAUSE LOGIC

  function scoreFunction() {
    if (square.classList.contains('valid')) {
      score += 3
    }
  }

  startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (paused === false) {

      score++
      return
    }
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 'Score' + ': ' + score++
      paused = false
    timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)

  })

  function pauseGame() {
    paused = true
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }

  pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pauseGame()
  })

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" dir="ltr">
  <title> Fizz-Buzz-Fizz!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="button-one"> Start </button>
  <button class="button-two"> Pause</button>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="star-crossed"> Star Crossed Collision!</div>
  <h1 class="score"> This is Your Score: </h1>
  <div class="countdown"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML? Also, where did you define `pauseBtn` or `startBtn`?

Comment: Hi! I put more of the JS in the code. Please let me know if this is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `}` after the `createBoard` function:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
  const startBtn = document.querySelector('.button-one')
  const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('.button-two')
  const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('.score')
  const countdown = document.querySelector('.countdown')
  let paused = true
  let score = 100
  const width = 8
  const squares = []
  let isGameOver = false
  let buzzyAmount = 12
  let result = 0

  const fiBuzz = [
    'url(images/purple-fizzy.png)',
    'url(images/buzzy-green.png)',
    'url(images/new-moo-buzzy.png)',
    'url(images/new-shiny-fizzy.png)'
  ]

  //shuffled Arrays

  function createBoard() {

    const buzzArray = Array(buzzyAmount).fill('buzzy')
    const emptyArray = Array(width * width - buzzyAmount).fill('valid')
    const gameArray = emptyArray.concat(buzzArray)
    const shuffledArray = gameArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)


    for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * fiBuzz.length)
      let square = document.createElement('div')
      square.setAttribute('id', i)
      square.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')
      square.classList.add(shuffledArray[i])
      grid.appendChild(square)
      squares.push(square)
      square.style.backgroundImage = fiBuzz[randomNumber]

      //normal click
      square.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        click(square)
      })
    }
  }

  // game over

  function gameOver(square) {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + '<br>' + ' You Lose :('
    isGameOver = true
    clearInterval(timerId)

    // show ALL the badStars in gameOver 
    squares.forEach(square => {
      if (square.classList.contains('buzzy')) {
        square.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = 'images/fizz-buzz-mix.png'
        square.classList.remove('buzzy')
        square.classList.add('checked')
        clearInterval(timerId)
      }
    })
  }

  function checkForWin() {

    let matches = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      if (score >= 100) {
        scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + ': ' + ' You Win!'
      } else {
        scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + ': ' + ' You Lose!'
      }
      clearInterval(timerId)
    }
  }

  // TIMER LOGIC

  const startingMinutes = .25
  let time = startingMinutes * 60
  let timerId
  let square

  function countDown() {

    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    let seconds = time % 60
    time--
    console.log(minutes, 'minutes:', seconds, 'seconds')


    if (time <= 0) {
      checkForWin()
      gameOver()
    }

    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '
  }


  // START AND PAUSE LOGIC

  function scoreFunction() {
    if (square.classList.contains('valid')) {
      score += 3
    }
  }

  startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (paused === false) {

      score++
      return
    }
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 'Score' + ': ' + score++
      paused = false
    timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)

  })

  function pauseGame() {
    paused = true
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }

  pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pauseGame()
  })

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" dir="ltr">
  <title> Fizz-Buzz-Fizz!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="button-one"> Start </button>
  <button class="button-two"> Pause</button>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="star-crossed"> Star Crossed Collision!</div>
  <h1 class="score"> This is Your Score: </h1>
  <div class="countdown"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you already have this concept in your code. You just need to attach that function to the button you want, through a click event listener.

Ex:

JS

```js
const thisButton = document.getElementById('thisButton');
thisButton.addEventListener('click', createBoard);
```

HTML

```html
<button id="thisButton">Start the game!</button>
```